# mlb.com live game video not working on Ubuntu after latest update

Tags: ubuntu, flash

After the latest Ubuntu update (which included upgrading Firefox to 3.0.12), the live game video (i.e. TV), which uses Flash, no longer works... it just splashes the team logos and then sits at a black screen.  The audio (i.e. radio) games still work.  Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now... must have been a problem on the mlb server that happened at the same time as my update.